# deploying Ignite cluster in pivotal cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, ignite

I am running 2 ignite nodes as 2 different applications in pivotal cloud foundry.
I had to use <app1_route>:47500..47510,<app2_route>:47500..47510 as ignite discovery URL in applications for both nodes to be in the same cluster. Can we deploy multiple ignite nodes in a single application(using processes, instances or any other) and get them under the same cluster instead of different applications?

Comment: I don't see why not. Can you please clarify your use case?

Comment: If i have 2 ignite nodes in same application, how will my ignite discovery url be?
Can we use multiple processes or instances and form a url which redirects to both nodes?

Comment: You can just use `new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder().setShared(true)`, I guess.

Comment: I am not sure how "TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder().setShared(true)" can be used, can you elaborate the cloud foundry settings and manifest settings @alamar

Comment: It may be used if both nodes belong to same Java process.